# Maximum flow - via vertex - how?

Tags: algorithm, graph

The problem:

Let G = (V, E) be a directed graph on n >=  3 vertices with m edges. The vertex set V includes three
special vertices a, v, and b. Find a simple path from a to b via v if it exists. (A simple path is a path without repeated vertices.)

I believe this problem should/can be solved with a Max Flow algorithm but I am not sure how. It reminds me of a Max Flow algorithm with multiple sources where the edges have capacity 1. Anyone know how the problem can be reduced to Maximum flow algorithm?

If I set vertex b as sink I can not be sure it will include v. If I set v as sink how do I continue when v is reached?

Comment: Wouldn't v just be the source of a second path to b?

Comment: You could try "maximum flow lower bound" on google. If you enforce a minimum flow of 1 through vertex v, then you essentially have a path through v.

Comment: @Mikeb I do not think so. The flow from a->v might be a path that makes it impossible to make a flow from v-b I think.

Comment: @phimuemue How to enforce a flow of 1 trough vertex v?

Comment: @phimuemue- This might not work correctly, since there might be a cycle in the graph and the flow lower bound might just end up routing flow through v in a flow cycle that has no connection to the flow path from a to b.

Comment: @bobjink: There are algorithms for such kind of flow problems -- however, as templatetypedef pointed out, this might not work at all...

Comment: I've found the following over on http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/dijkstra.html: It says: Once thing we haven't looked at is the problem of finding shortest paths that must go through certain points. This is a hard problem and is reducible to the Travelling Salesman problem--what this means in practice is that it can take a very long time to solve the problem even for very small inputs. Don't know if this applies for the special case of only 1 intermediate vertex...

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I am wrong and this problem does not apply to Maximum Flow as I i thought.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

- find all *minimal* paths from `a` to `v`, that *do not contain* vertex `b`. You can get those by (e.g.) a DFS on the graph without vertex `b`. We say that an `a-v`-path `p` is minimal, if no other `a-v`-path `p'` contains only vertices from `p`.
- for each minimal `a-v`-path, try to find a path from `v` to `b` ignoring vertices already belonging to the `a-v`-path. If you find such a thing, you're done.

*Remark:* Note that the number of paths might grow exponential, but as I pointed out in my comment, at least the generalized version of this problem seems to be reducible to the TSP, thus being probably very difficult.

Comment: This is also the only solution I can find. Not the answer I was hoping for :/

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to asking if a graph contains a subgraph homeomorphic to a directed path with three vertices (a pattern is a graph on some of the vertices from the input graph, and a subgraph is homeomorphic to a pattern if edges of the pattern can be mapped to simple, pairwise vertex disjoint paths of the subgraph). It has been proven by [Fortune, Hopcroft, and Wyllie](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975%2880%2990009-2) that directed subgraph homeomorphism is NP-hard for almost all fixed patterns, including this. So the problem is NP-hard, and cannot be solved by flow techniques unless P = NP.

The undirected version though can be reduced to maximum flow though by having a and b be the source and v the sink.